# Access parameter/variable passed to Invoke-call

Tags: c#, dynamic, lambda, expression, expression-trees

I'm trying to build some dynamic queries for my underlying database using LinqKit and the expandable-extensions.

In my code I have a property which looks like

```
private Expression<Func<MyModel, MyConfig, MyResult>> Parent
{
    get
    {
        var modelParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyModel), "myModel");
        var configParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyConfig), "config");

        var conditionalExpression = Expression.Call(configParam, typeof(MyConfig).GetMethod("ShowParent"), Expression.Constant("SomeName"));

        // how to decide whether to return an expression or null?

        // build expression or return constant null-expression
    }
}
```

which I call `Parent.Invoke(myModel, config)`.

Is there any chance to gain access to the config-param which is passed to the Invoke-call to determine inside the getter whether to return a real `Expression` or just `null`?

The `MyConfig` class has a method `bool ShowParent(string parentName)` which I would like to call inside the getter to determine what to do?

Is this possible that way? If not, are there any good points where to start with?

Comment: You cannot check the passed `config` parameter in the getter where you generate the expression. Instead, you need to generate an `if` expression inside the expression to check it.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I've updated my question. I've built the call to `ShowParent` but get stuck there as I don't know how to decide depending on the call